# Make an simple Android App / Webview & local pages

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to build a simple app, using Webview.
I just want to create an app that contains 2 html files (stored in assets folder). At loading, app display page1.html in webview.
On this page, there is a link to page2.html (in html format : href=""). I need this page opens also in webview.

I tried, but when I click on the link, the app closes... I tried href="page2.html", href="file:///android_asset/page2.html"... Nothing works.

Do you have any example of a simple app like this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: I mean come-on a member from 9 years? . Please read [ask] and add a [mcve] with question including the crash logs . You can go to above link to see how to find stacktrace of crash .